# How to add manifest (required for third-party assembly) to C# class library?

Tags: c#, manifest

Similar questions have been asked before but I have tried everything to no avail.

One distinction is that my product is a class library, not an application.  Though if there were a way to "drop in" a file like "myapplication.exe.manifest" we could probably do that.  But essentially our library is using an SDK, and that SDK has a manifest file that has to go along with any use of the SDK.

Typically we would like our class library to simply load as a plugin, with all its dependencies properly established. But the manifest is not working here.

If I write an actual application, indeed I can add the manifest to the project, and then specify the manifest in the project Properties (in the Application section).  For Class libraries this option is disabled, but yes I have been able to add an application manifest (via the available templates), and paste in the required contents.  I can confirm that there is a manifest embedded by viewing the DLL in VS directly (file/open) and seeing that RT_MANIFEST is defined. But the SDK has COMExceptions during initialization, unless/until I resort to attaching it to the application.

This is the content of the manifest that is required for all usages of the third-party SDK we are using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" 
            xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" 
            xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" 
            xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="VideoOS.UI"/>
    <file name="ImageViewerDotNet.dll">
       <comClass clsid="{b86e5a61-3f0d-4efd-a040-a68a301a1bfa}"/>
    </file>
    <file name="AudioPlayerDotNet.dll">
       <comClass clsid="{31b3afb3-462a-4135-80c4-151649ccd0d5}" />
    </file>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

To be clear: VideoOS.UI is not the name of our assembly but is part of the SDK we are using.  So right now attaching the manifest to the application is the only way that we are able to use the SDK.  No luck with the approach of simply creating a .exe.manifest.

Does it have something to do with the fact I am defining the dependencies for a *different* assembly than my own?

[Note: Applying the manifest to the application is not going to work very well as this particular SDK/plugin is not a universal feature of the application.]

Comment: Pay attention to the resource ID you find under RT_MANIFEST.  It must be 2, not 1.

Comment: @HansPassant indeed it has been 2, whether I add to the assembly with MT.exe or directly in the build.  I'm fine if I run it mt.exe on the .exe but never on the .dll that directly uses the SDK.